# Updating old apps to run on tablets

Tags: android, upgrade, tablet

I have a load of apps written to target 1.6 (old school)

Is there a guide to show how to upgrade the apps sothat they work on tablets. We use the Menu and back button a lot in the apps and we're looking to now have to re-write much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html) link. Google recently put out a kind of "training" series on how to handle different things such as adaptive UI flows, navigation, layout optimization, how to maintain multiple APKs, and more.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a guide to do that but if you want to do a good job you have to learn and understand the new guide lines and best practices for ICS.

For example you have (imho you must!) use the ActionBar.

I'm reading [this guides](http://commonsware.com/Android/) and I think they are very good.

As someone said after me google has also released an official training site to learn directly many things. Here you have [Android Training](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html).

Also I suggest you to take a look to video talks released during past Google I/O. Very interesting :)